# Having problems compiling ffmpeg for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg for Android using this [guy script](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg) (https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg) because it looked like the simplest and the whole NDK is really not my area of expertise.

So let's see what I've done so far:

- Downloaded and installed a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop in a VirtualBox. (had some little problems with video but a few updates later in the terminal ubuntu is up and running)
- installed the Android SDk and [downloded/unzipped the NDK](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86.tar.bz2) into `/Documents/ndk`
- I used those commands to install the compiler:

> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get upgrade
>
> $ sudo apt-get install build-essential
>
> $ gcc -v
>
> $ make -v

- then `sudo install git` (or something like that to install git)
- then `git clone https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg.git`
- then copied from the guys page `building` section
- `cd android-ffmpeg`
- `git submodule init`
- `git submodule update`
- `NDK_BASE=/path/to/android-ndk ./configure_make_everything.sh`

it mostly goes well until it says:

> arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file C
>   compiler test failed
>
> If you think configure made a mistake,.. blaah blahh blaah

I'm not sure what it means or where to go from here.
from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12912908/906362) I did some `chmod 777` on the folders to make sure stuff can be execute.

also from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660043/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-is-unable-to-create-an-executable-compile-ffmpeg-fo) I tried his script but without any luck.

help?

Answer (score 2):

decompose what the script 'config_make_everything' is doing.. and run one step  at a time...

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg/blob/master/configure_make_everything.sh

each step will create a file like 'config.log' where you can go to the tail and find more details about what went wrong finding the compiler.

When u start using the NDK, IMO,  invest a bit of learn curve time going thru its ./doc directory and making sure that you have it integrated correctly. With NDK install, there are some samples. Build a few from CLI just to make sure that the ENV is correct and that the install is good, and that u have at least some idea of the build as a repeatable process. That will prove that you can do good 'cross compiles' with the build tools. Then you can return to guardian.ffmpeg stuff.

IMO - there is alot going on with an NDK build of this project and getting it all to build without understanding any of the underlying configuration / build stack would require lots of luck.

Comment: I'm shutting down for today but I'll certainly give a try on your comments, tips, suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Using NDK, you should have a lil understand of what a 'cross-toolchain' is and how it gets it's compiler. Thats in the 'docs' directory. Then, with guardian, you should know at least some of what each step in 'build_all" is doing.. where the input is , where the config is , where the output is...